# Import external script with angular and storybook 7

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, storybook, createjs

I'm using a storybook 7 instance with angular 14 and want to import createjs. In `angular.json` createjs is being imported as a script:

```json
"scripts": [
  {
    "input": "node_modules/createjs/builds/1.0.0/createjs.js",
    "inject": false,
    "bundleName": "createjs"
  }
]
```

The bundle is created as createjs.js and it's also being loaded. Nevetheless `createjs` is not defined in the components.

Usage is like this:

```js
...
declare var createjs: any;
...

@Component({
...
})
export class SomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(createjs); // <-- undefined
  }
}
```

Doing exactly the same without storybook works well in angular.

The difference I saw is the way the script is being appended to the body. Storybook+Angular appends it as `<script type="module">import createjs.js;</script>` and Angular appends it as `<script>source code of the script</script>`;

The Storybook+Angular version leads to an undefined "this" inside of the loaded script itself.

I would really appreciate any thoughts on this! Thanks!

Comment: I found a workaround to solve my issue, by adding the required script to .storybook/preview-body.html (https://storybook.js.org/docs/angular/configure/story-rendering). It's not ideal but at least the SB7 upgrade works now. I'm still looking for a better solution :-)